# Jqgrid file upload path

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I am using the code like this for file  upload. After click the edit button the event fire into ashx page. And also read the value from form.get method. But i can't able to get the path of the file upload. Please help me to get this.

```
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({
    url:'handler.ashx',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'GET',
    colNames:['Seriel Number', 'Script Name', 'Script Location','Host Url','Protocol','Rampup Time','No of Users','Loop','Delay'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'sr_no',index:'sr_no', width:55,editable:false,editoptions:{readonly:true,size:10},hidden:true},
        {name:'script_name',index:'script_name', width:100,editable:true, editrules:{required:false}, editoptions:{size:10, maxlength: 15}},
        {name:'script_loc',index:'script_loc', width:100,editable:true, editrules:{required:false},edittype: 'file', editoptions:{enctype: "multipart/form-data"}},
        {name:'host_url',index:'host_url', width:100,editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{ size:10, maxlength: 25}},
        {name:'protocol',index:'protocol', width:100,editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:10, maxlength: 10}},
        {name:'rampup_time',index:'rampup_time', width:100,editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{defaultValue: '0',size:2, maxlength: 4}},
        {name:'noof_users',index:'noof_users', width:100,editable:true, editrules:{required:false}, editoptions:{size:4, maxlength: 8}},
        {name:'loops',index:'loops', width:100,editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{defaultValue: '1'  ,size:1, maxlength: 2}},
        {name:'delay',index:'delay', width:100,editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{defaultValue: '0',size:1, maxlength: 4}}                      
    ],
    postData: { 
    },
    rowNum:20,
    rowList:[20,40,60],
    height: 200,
    autowidth: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    pager: '#pager',
    sortname: 'sr_no',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "asc",
    caption:"Users",
    emptyrecords: "Empty records",
    loadonce: false,
    loadComplete: function() {
    },
})
```

Comment: Which column in jqgrid here has attached file, for which u want to get path

Comment: script_loc is the file upload column

Comment: Ok. You are unable to get only path or entire grid columns

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i have used jqgrid in my code. use this code as reference.I dont say this is exact colution but it may be of use for you.
In my jqgrid script i have specified url with param  as url:'controller.aspx?p=load'

```
    jQuery("#jQGridDemo").jqGrid({
     url: 'controller.aspx?p=load',
     datatype: 'json',
     mtype: 'POST',
     colNames: ['Job Order #', 'Part #', 'Operation #' ...],
     colModel: [...]
     ....
     ....
    });
```

In my controller.aspx page:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.AddHeader("Content-type", "text/javascript");

     if (Request.Params["p"].Equals("load"))
     {
        bool success = true;
        OrderEntity[] arrReturn = Order.getOrderArray(0, -1);
        int arry_size = arrReturn.Length;

        string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arrReturn);
        string ret = "{data:" + data + ",\n";
        ret += "recordType : 'object'}";
        if (data == null)
        {
            success = false;
            Response.Write("0");
        }
        if (success == true)
        {
            Response.Write(data);
        }
       }
      }
```

refer this code in question on jqgrid-handler example [handler with jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16058996/jqgrid-handler-for-more-than-one-grid)

Comment: I can read the other values from the form. But i can't get the path of the file upload control what i select.